# Array inside array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm developing a webapplication where there is a page that you can see the listed items that you placed on the website.

When I fetch some results from the DB I can end up with two cars that he/she listed. Which will end up something like this:

carID: 1

- model: R8
- Brand: Audi
- Color: Yellow

carID: 2

- Model: Audi TT
- Brand: Audi
- Color: White

When I try use the function while `(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)` it will overwrite the last `carID` and it will never end up with two cars. Here is my code:

```
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
    $car_id_array = $carid;
    $final_array = array($car_id_array => array(

        "brand"     => $brand,
        "color"     => $color,
        "type"      => $type,
        "price"     => $price,
        "mileage"   => $mileage,
        "model"     => $model,
        "year"      => $year   

                                                )

                        );

}

foreach($final_array as $final_array_key => $final_array_value){

    foreach($final_array_value as $car_id_array_key => $car_id_array_value){

        echo $final_array_key . " ----> " . $car_id_array_key . ":" . $car_id_array_value;
        echo "<br>";
    }

}
```

I would like to end up with the two `carID` into the `final_array`.

Comment: Change this line `$final_array = array($car_id_array => array(` to `$final_array[] = array($car_id_array => array(`. You can read more in the PHP docs about array syntax and [adding elements to an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using two arrays when you can end up using only indexes?

Try this code:

```
$i++;
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
        $final_array[$i] = array(
            "carid"     => $carid,
            "brand"     => $brand,
            "color"     => $color,
            "type"      => $type,
            "price"     => $price,
            "mileage"   => $mileage,
            "model"     => $model,
            "year"      => $year          

        );
$i++;
}

        foreach ($final_array as $key => $value){
            echo $key . ":" . $value;
            echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
```

Comment: You don't need the `$i` either. With `[]` PHP will auto generate the key.

Comment: @chris85 I did'nt know that. Thank you.